# Use of @EJB annotation on Liferay 6.1 MVCPortlet

Tags: ejb, liferay-6, inject

Is it possible to inject EJB on MVCPortlet types (Liferay 6.1 on JBoss 7 as) the way we used to do with servlets and JSF managed beans (with the `@EJB` annotation)?

Answer (score 0):

Curious about the same thing, so I setup a test using JBoss AS 7.1.1 and liferay 6.1 with a portlet I made with Liferay IDE

It does not appear to work.

```
public class TestEjbPortlet extends MVCPortlet
{
    @EJB 
    TestService testService;

    public  void doView (RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws PortletException, IOException 
    {
        if (testService != null)
        {
            System.out.println( " works " + testService.getTest());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println( " EJB failed to inject in view" );
        }

     }
}
```

output:

09:55:57,975 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1)  EJB failed to inject in view